# Waking an Ibook G4 (powerpc) running Debian Linux from suspend based on timer

Tags: debian, suspend, powerpc, sleep

I have recently received an Ibook G4 from a friend.  I plan to use it as a server and have installed Debian Wheezy (7.0.0, release version) on it.  However, I would like to suspend it at some points and wake it up - either after a specified time period or when the power cable is plugged in.

As per the documentation for [pbbuttonsd](http://pbbuttons.berlios.de/projects/pbbuttonsd/doc.html), which seems to be slightly more powerful and up to date than pmud, there is in fact an option in the Power Management Unit on these computers to wake up on the basis of a time period.  However, the [pbbuttonsd manpage](http://pbbuttons.berlios.de/projects/pbbuttonsd/man-pbbuttonsd.html) simply says "Other wake up options [other than wake up on button press or lid open] are not foreseen by the kernel at this time."  Since that documentation dates from 2007, I am hoping that this is no longer true.

Trying out the standard `rtcwake` command gives me an error, saying there is no wakeup option in the /sys directory.

Is there any way to wake up this computer on the basis of a timer / when it is plugged in?

**NB**: I believe that Wheezy uses kernel version 3.2.0.